# Resouce only DLL In C# , cannot access resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several C# projects which should use the same resources. Therefore I used  the approach of creating a common resource DLL which only provides the resources.

The resources which are all strings for localization were first on one of the  projects , and that project worked without a problem using its local resources. problems start when I have moved my resources to the DLL.

How did I do it :

I created a class library Named **Common**.
Under the Common project I have **resources.resx** (Under Properties) I have all the strings there and I have Access modifier set to **public**.

On my project(s) I have referenced the Common project.

I am trying to use these resources from two difference locations :
1. .CS Files
2. from XAML.

In the .CS File I am doing :

```
m_ResourceManager = new ResourceManager("Common.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetExecutiongAssembly();
m_ResourceManager.GetString("MyString");
```

Calling GetString throw an exception of missing resource.

In my XAML :

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Common.Properties".....
<Label Content="{x:Static p:Resources.MyString}".....
```

With the XAML, the project does not compile and says no Resources section could be found on each of my x:Static.

Again, changing everything to my local resource works perfectly. it just when trying to access it via my DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your assembly explicitly, because now you are trying to load resources from the current executing assembly. For example:

CS:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Common.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Common.Properties;assembly=Common"
```

*It has been found by question author that **VS2013 requires Update 2** or above to make it work. Also, I was unable to reproduce this issue on VS2015 CE.

Comment: And what is my resource assembly if I placed them in my Common.dll file ?

Comment: Common.dll is your assembly. Edited the answer for your Common.dll. Supposing that your Common project contains Resources type and is referenced by your application.

Comment: what about typeof(Resources) what Resources means ? Writing it down as-is provide an error.

Comment: Both of the CS and XAML options didn't work. It seems that he can not resolve the name space. I have been looking in my Common project resources.resx designer CS file and the namespace is Common.Properties. I did Add reference to the Common project and see it in the reference list.. so what is the problem?

Comment: Resources is a class that generated automatically in code behind of your Resources.resx file. Another problem could be if in the editor of Resources.resx "Access Modifier" combobox at the top of the page is not set to Public. It is Internal by default. Could you please try to set it to Public?

Comment: You can open Resources.Designer.cs file and check is Resources class is public.

Comment: Also when trying to add the xmlns:p in my XAML the auto complete suggest Common.Properties and state (MyProjectName) and not (Common). I add a different namespace and noticed the assembly= was added with my auto-complete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98110/discussion-between-anton-danylov-and-nuno-147).